# $ \lim_{n\to\infty} {2n\choose n}^{(1/n)}$

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}{2n\choose n}^{(1/n)}$$
​   I tried it with Riemann sum and I got that an interval that is divergent.
Can somebody provide me a solution using Riemann sum as I think that I mistaken something.

Comment: Hint: use $4^n=(1+1)^{2n}=\sum \binom{2n}{k}$ to bound the central binomial coefficient (divide by number of terms for lower bound...)

Answer (score 4):

We have the bounds $\displaystyle \frac{4^{n}}{2n+1}\leq \binom{2n}{n}\leq 4^{n}$ from the Binomial Theorem on $(1 + 1)^{2n}$. Then by the Squeeze Theorem we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{4^{n}}{2n+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(4^{n}\big)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$\frac{4}{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2n+1}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq 4$$

It is well known that the limit in the denominator is equal to $1$, so:

$$4\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq 4$$

$$\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}} = 4}$$

Comment: I recommend making the lower bound $\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$.